# Basic Multiplication Rule vs Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

I'm looking at old probability problems and trying to interpret them in different ways to test my understanding.  Given information in this problem:

- probability of being windy = .2
- Probability rain on windy day = .3
- Probability rain on non-windy day = .8

Question: What is probability given day is both windy and rainy?

I understand that $P(Wind \wedge Rain) = P(W)P(R|W)$ by interpreting the conditional probability as shrinking the outcome space.  Since I'm given the probability of it being windy, I thought I could condition on it like so:

$ P(WR) = P(WR | W) = P(W|W) P(R|W) = $ above answer

Is this interpretation useful or even accurate?   It seems to return the same answer but this part of the statement bothers me $P(WR) = P(WR | W)$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$P(WR) = P(WR | W) = P(W|W) P(R|W) =$ above answer" is not accurate

- The first equality claims to say that *the probability of wind and rain is the probability of wind and rain given wind*.  This is not correct as it ignores the possibility of no wind.  A better statement might be $P(WR) = P(WR \mid W) P(W)$
- The second equality claims to say that *the probability of wind and rain given wind is the probability of wind given wind multiplied by the probability of rain given wind*.  This is correct but is not particularly informative
- The third equality claims to say that *the probability of wind given wind multiplied by the probability of rain given wind is the probability of wind  multiplied by the probability of rain given wind*.  This is not correct as $P(W \mid W)=1 \not = 0.2 = P(W)$

$P(WR) = P(W)P(R\mid W)$ is a basic statement of conditional probability and gives you the answer since you know $P(W)=0.2$ and  $P(R\mid W)=0.3$

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts serve you well. Usually the notation $P(WR) = P(W \wedge R)$.

In general, $P(WR) = P(W | R) \cdot P (R) = P(R | W) \cdot P (W)$. Moreover, $P(AB|B) = P(A|B)$ since $B$ is already given.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$0.3=P(R|W)=\dfrac{P(R\cap W)}{P(W)}=\dfrac{P(R\cap W)}{0.2}\implies P(R\cap W)=0.06.$$